# Factorization of the polynomial: $m^2+3m^2n^2-30n^2-10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How can we factor the polynomial  $m^2+3m^2n^2-30n^2-10$ ?

Comment: $m^2(1+3n^2)-10(1+3n^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ m^2+3m^2n^2-30n^2-10=m^2(1+3n^2)-10(1+3n^2)
=(1+3n^2)(m^2-10)$

This is the answer.

Comment: @ArshiaMoniri, it is not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are no nontrivial polynomial factors.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the problem. It is $m^2+3m^2n^2-30n^2-10$.

Answer (score 0):

$m^2 +3n^2(m^2-10)- 10$

$m^2-10 + 3n^2(m^2-10)$

$(m^2-10)(1 + 3n^2)$